# Chart.js v2 - how to set dataset-dependent date formats in tooltips

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In Chart.js (v2.7.3) I have a line chart containing multiple datasets. I'd like to show the date in the tooltips in 'MMM' format for one of the datasets (which has one point in each month), and 'D MMM' format for all others (which have varying numbers of points per month).

I've tried using a function for tooltipFormat, as shown below:

```
time: {
    parser: timeFormat,
    round: 'day',
    tooltipFormat: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var f = 'D MMM';
        if(tooltipItem.datasetIndex==0){
            f = 'MMM';
        }
        return f;
    },
    unit: 'month',
    displayFormats: {
        day: 'MMM',
        month: 'MMM'
    }
}
```

However with the above, whenever I hover over a point on any line, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: format.replace is not a function
    at expandFormat (moment-with-locales.js:626)
    at formatMoment (moment-with-locales.js:611)
    at Moment.format (moment-with-locales.js:3351)
    at ChartElement.getLabelForIndex (Chart.js:14331)
    at createTooltipItem (Chart.js:8354)
    at ChartElement.update (Chart.js:8735)
    at ChartElement.handleEvent (Chart.js:9097)
    at Chart.eventHandler (Chart.js:4704)
    at listener (Chart.js:4633)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.proxies.(anonymous function) (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.7.3/dist/Chart.js:10970:4)
```

This works just fine, but sets all tooltips to 'D MMM':

```
time: {
    parser: timeFormat,
    round: 'day',
    tooltipFormat: 'D MMM',
    unit: 'month',
    displayFormats: {
        day: 'MMM',
        month: 'MMM'
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work - same 'Uncaught TypeError: format.replace is not a function' error:

```
time: {
    parser: timeFormat,
    round: 'day',
    tooltipFormat: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        return 'D MMM';
    },
    unit: 'month',
    displayFormats: {
        day: 'MMM',
        month: 'MMM'
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to use a function for tooltipFormat, or am I just doing this wrong?

Comment: it seems like the error came from `moment.js`. could you pls add a snippet here or a fiddle link with the problem visible ?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting a fiddle to work, but I've just added some more code which might be helpful. Basically if I write `tooltipFormat: 'D MMM',` instead of using a function, it works fine, but of course shows 'D MMM' format for all tooltips. If I simplify the function to simply `return 'MMM';`, (also included in edits), that doesn't work either.

Comment: Official [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#configuration-options) says `time.tooltipFormat` should be `string`

Comment: I had feared that might be the case. I'll see if I can do something with the label instead. Thanks for your help!